# Russian Cases, Grammar & огонём vs огнём

Tags: падежи, беглая-гласная

Don't play with fire, it is dangerous!

1. Не играть с огонём, это опаснаый! (This was what I translated.)
2. Не играй с огнём, это опасно! (This was from a native speaker.)

Questions :

1. How did играть (I believe this is a nominative case) becomes играй?
2. Is there any different between these two spellings, огонём & огнём? Why one of them is correct?
3. How did опаснаый (nominative case?) becomes опасно?

Comment: please, tend to ask one question per post

Answer (score 6):

1. `играй` is the [imperative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) form that is used for making command and requests.
2. огонём does not exist, the only correct form is `огнём` - the middle o is dropped - when vowel behaves like that it's called `беглая гласная`.
   How can you learn that? You can check the article at [wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C). See the phrase "тип склонения 2*b по классификации А. А. Зализняка"? Zaliznyak is a Russian linguist who made an attempt to classify all possible inclinations that exist in Russian. So, what does 2*b mean? Let's [look it up](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C:%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> - **2** — слова с основой на мягкий согласный (тюлень, искатель, цапля, Дуня, горе, поле; весенний)
> - **b** — ударение всегда вне основы, если кроме основы вообще что-либо есть (топор, похвала, вещество, родной)
> - **Звездочка при цифре** означает чередование в основе беглой гласной с нулём (1*a, 3*a и т. п.; платок, кошка, сердце)

That's how you basically can figure it out.

3. опаснаый does not exist, the only correct form is `опасный` from which [`опасно`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE) is derived.

Answer (score 5):

***1)*** The [prohibitive form](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) (Ru) with an infinitive (***не*** + the infinitive) is more official and is used in a colloquial speech as a form of rude impersonal command only:

***Не играть с огнём. => Не играй с огнём.***

***Не дразнить собаку. => Не дразни собаку.***

Basically, any verb of the ***-ать*** type changes into its singular imperative mode by the same algorythm:

***Не дела***+***ть*** ***ничего***. => ***Не дела***+***й*** ***ничего***.

***Не отдава***+***ть*** ***деньги.*** => ***Не отдава***+***й***  ***деньги***.

***Не счита***+***ть*** ***деньги***. => ***Не счита***+***й***  ***деньги***.

and so on.

***2)*** The difference in forms *** *огонём / огнём*** is related to [another question previously asked by a different user about 'ghost vowels'](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14476/declension-of-%D0%BB%D0%B5%CC%81%D0%B2/14478#14478).

***3)*** By default, a neutrum form of an adjective is required in a sentence similar to that with '[dummy pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun)' in most Western languages (those of 'it/that's great'-type, or as a predicate complement for a verb (that is, whenever a topic of a sentence is expressed by an infinitive, in phrases of 'to-live-is-to-love'-type).

The universal neutrum ending for a singular neutrum form of any adjective is ***-o***. Technically, the resulting form is a[n modal] adverb, but Russian doesn't distinguish between these two.

***Это опасная игра. = Это опасно. = Играть так - опасно / Опасно так играть.***

***Это важное дело. = Это важно. = Делать так - важно. / Важно так делать. / Важно делать так.***

***Это обидная дразнилка.  = Это обидно. =  Дразнить так - обидно / Обидно так дразнить.***

***Это большой счёт. = Это много. = Считать столько будет много. = Много будет так считать.***

***Это большая отдача / большой результат. = Это много и хорошо. = Отда(ва)ть столько - много и хорошо. = Много и хорошо будет столько отда(ва)ть.***